# Wireless card can only connect to certain networks

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, ralink

I just did my first install of Ubuntu 11.04. I can connect to my neighbors' unsecured Wi-Fi networks, but not my own (secured) Wi-Fi network.

I have a Ralink RT2070 (the cheapest wireless thingy I could find on Newegg).

It came with drivers that seem to only work in Fedora, Windows 7, and on a Mac; however I did not need these drivers with Windows 7.

Comment: Could you provide additional information about your drivers?

Comment: @Zian Oops, forgot to add that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way Linux works (if you're lucky) is that the drivers are already in the kernel. They come as part of the deal. It sounds like you're in luck because you can get online. But it does look like you'll have to do some blacklisting, in particular:

`echo 'blacklist rt3070sta' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Read [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1718254) for more information before you do anything.

It's also advisable to make a back-up of your `blacklist.conf` file before you alter it in any way. You can do this by opening a terminal and doing:

`sudo cp /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.bak`

Comment: How would I recover my `blacklist.conf` file from the `blacklist.conf.bak file`?

Comment: One way would be to do the same thing but in reserve, i.e. `sudo cp /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.bak /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the late "Accepted Answer" mark, I just haven't booted into Linux on this machine in a while.

Comment: @JavaAndCSharp: Not a problem. Glad it worked out for you.